# Error "hours cannot be resolved to a variable", what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, variables

```
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a military time: ");
    int time = kb.nextInt();
    int minutes = (time%100);
    if (time < 1){
        System.out.println("Illegal time, please give another one.");
    }else if (time%100>59){
        System.out.println("Illegal time, please give another one.");
    }else if (time>2400){
        System.out.println("Illegal time, please give another one.");
    }else{
        if (time<100){
            final int hours = 12;
        }else if (time<1300){
            final int hours = (time/100);
        }else{
            final int hours = ((time/100)-12); }
        if (minutes<10)
            System.out.println("Standard time is: "+hours+":0"+minutes);
        else if (minutes>=10)
            System.out.println("Standard time is: "+hours+":"+minutes);
```

This is a program to convert military time to standard time. I continuously get the error "hours cannot be resolved to a variable", but do not understand what is wrong with my code. Any help of insight would be helpful.

Comment: `hours` is not in scope anymore when you try to print it to the console. Declare it where you have declared `time` and `minutes`.

Comment: in your last 2 if statements, your hours declarations arent being found. you need to fix your logic

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `hours` in each of the `if` case blocks, but since the block immediately ends, `hours` immediately goes out of scope.

Declare it before the `if`, so it remains in scope where you need it.

```
final int hours;  // Not initialized yet.
if (time<100){
   hours = 12;
}else if (time<1300){
   hours = (time/100);
}else{
   hours = ((time/100)-12); }
// Now it's still in scope here:
if (minutes<10)
    System.out.println("Standard time is: "+hours+":0"+minutes);
else if (minutes>=10)
    System.out.println("Standard time is: "+hours+":"+minutes);
```

Note that the compiler is smart enough to determine that the `final` variable `hours` is initialized exactly once in each case, so it won't complain that the variable might not have been initialized or that the variable might have been changed after it was inititalized.